# How do coverage super method on Constructor method with mockito and junit?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

i need to coverage this :

```
public class SimulationDialog extends DialogView {

    private static final double BUTTON_STEP = 1;
    private static final double STEPPER_MIN = 0;
    private static final double STEPPER_MAX_CNH = 7500;
    private static final double STEPPER_MAX_AG_LEADER = 426000;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimulationDialog.class);

    private float currentStepperValue;
    private boolean isSwitchOn;

    /**
     * Used to receive UI changes from the raw force widget
     */
    public interface SimulationDialogListener {
        /**
         * Called when switching simulator ON or OFF
         *
         * @param started true if the toggle button is set to ON, false otherwise
         */
        void onSimulationToggle(boolean started);

        /**
         * Called when updating the user updates the simulation raw force value
         *
         * @param rawForce the raw force value input by the user in the {@link StepperView}
         */
        void onSimulatedRawForceUpdated(double rawForce);
    }

    private SimulationDialogListener listener;
    private OnOffSwitch onOffSwitch;
    private StepperView stepperView;
    private TextView simulationNote;
    private FrameLayout stepperBg;

    public SimulationDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    protected void init() {
        DialogView dialogView = setBodyView(R.layout.simulation_dialog);
        this.onOffSwitch = (OnOffSwitch) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.toggleSimulation);
        this.stepperView = (StepperView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.fakeRawForce);
        this.simulationNote = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.simulationNote);
        this.stepperBg = (FrameLayout) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.stepper_bg);

        this.stepperView.setOnKeyboardValueUpdateListener(new StepperView.OnKeyboardValueUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKeyboardValueInserted(float keyValue) {
                currentStepperValue = keyValue;
                listener.onSimulatedRawForceUpdated(currentStepperValue);
                return false;
            }
        });
     ......
```

Any my Test is - SimulationDialogTest.java:

```
package com.cnh.pf.android.libymui.dialog;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.cnh.android.dialog.DialogView;
import com.cnh.android.widget.control.OnOffSwitch;
import com.cnh.android.widget.control.StepperView;
import com.cnh.pf.android.libymui.R;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyBoolean;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.spy;

/**
 * Created by Tiago Santos on 04/03/2024
 */


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@PrepareForTest({LayoutInflater.class})
public class SimulationDialogTest {

    @Mock
    private DialogView mockDialogView;
    @Mock
    private OnOffSwitch mockOnOffSwitch;
    @Mock
    private TextView mockSimulationNote;
    @Mock
    private FrameLayout mockStepperBg;
    @Mock
    private Context mockContext;
    @Mock
    private DialogView dialogView;
    @Mock
    private StepperView mockStepperView;
    @Mock
    private OnOffSwitch onOffSwitch;
    @Mock
    private SimulationDialog.SimulationDialogListener listenerMock;
    @Mock
    private  View dialogViewMock;
    @Mock
    private LayoutInflater mockLayoutInflater;

    private SimulationDialog simulationDialog;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        simulationDialog = spy(new SimulationDialog(mockContext));

        mockStatic(LayoutInflater.class);

        when(LayoutInflater.from(mockContext)).thenReturn(mockLayoutInflater);
        when(mockLayoutInflater.inflate(eq(R.layout.simulation_dialog), any(FrameLayout.class), anyBoolean())).thenReturn(dialogViewMock);

        simulationDialog.init();

    }


    @Test
    public void testInit() {
        
    }


}
```

when i insert breakpoint on my debug in super(context) , he talks that the super method is faulty, and returns NullPointerException on super(context) line..

Could anyone help me cover these tests? I need to coverage the init() method. Can anyone help me?

I tried different ways to resolve and coverage the code lines.